# WIA for wireless Scanner

Tags: c#, wpf, scanning, wia

I am having an application, that will scan documents, and I am using Windows Image Acquisition. I applied what's instructed in [this article](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/01/08/scanning-images-in-wpf-via-wia) written by Pete Brown, it's quite interesting but in my case, I have a wireless scanner, my code throws an exception that it doesn't find a device. I tries to enumerate the devices using this code I found:

```
public static List<string> GetDevices()
{
    List<string> devices = new List<string>();
    WIA.DeviceManager manager = new WIA.DeviceManager();

    foreach (WIA.DeviceInfo info in manager.DeviceInfos)
    {
         devices.Add(info.DeviceID);
    }

    return devices;
}
```

but the returned list is empty.

So is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you mean wireless scanner? WIA does not deal with printers...

Comment: Yes a scanner, I'll change it right now ( I have a 3 in one printer)

Comment: Does your scanner show up when you use select dialog - `new WIA.CommonDialog().ShowSelectDevice()`? Perhaps your device does not have WIA-compatible drivers...

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, since, as I mentioned, it works when I connect my scanner directly.

Answer (score 0):

When I use

```
WIA.DeviceManager manager = new WIA.DeviceManagerClass();
```

instead of

```
WIA.DeviceManager manager = new WIA.DeviceManager();
```

the `manager.DeviceInfos` includes my network Scanner.

Comment: The statement `WIA.DeviceManager manager = WIA.DeviceManagerClass()` won't compile.

Comment: In Visual Studio I add in "Reference Manager" -> "COM" -> "Type Libraries" the "Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition Library v2.0" for WIA.
VS than show me WIA.DeviceManagerClass() as Class of the interface WIA.DeviceManager(). Maybe we use different versions?

Comment: Yes, I use WIA v2.0. When I write `var manager = WIA.DeviceManagerClass()`, it says "Non-invocable member 'DeviceManagerClass' cannot be used like a method." When I write `var manager = new WIA.DeviceManagerClass()`, it says "Interop type 'DeviceManagerClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead."

Comment: Oh yes I forget the `new`-Keyword, I edited my solution to `new WIA.DeviceManagerClass();`.
But the hint to use the interface instead, I didn't get.

Comment: All 3 possible declarations without errors direct from my project:
`WIA.DeviceManager man1 = new WIA.DeviceManagerClass();
WIA.DeviceManagerClass man2 = new WIA.DeviceManagerClass();
var man3 = new WIA.DeviceManagerClass();`

Comment: OK, I think I know what happened -- you have set "Embed Interop" to false, right?

Comment: Yes thats right, all our assembly references have set the "Embed Interop Types" property to false as default.